# Group by taxonomy headers

Tags: views, navigation

Not sure why I can't do this as it sounds simple, I have:

A content type called 'RSS FEEDS'

A vocabulary called 'Publications' within this I have 3 terms which are 1) NY Times 2) BBC 3) National Geographic

I now have a bunch of nodes that are tagged with these 3 terms.

What I want to do is have an accordion with 3 headers:

NY Times,
BBC,
National Geographic

So when I click a header I see all the nodes of that particular type underneath. I have tried an number of things including aggregation, taxonomy views etc but cannot seem to work this out. For clarity I have mocked up how I want this to look.

Any help greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: There is choice to group by headers in the view accordion settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You're almost done, but missed some settings ;). You just need to do some Format settings for Views Accordion in your View.

Here are the steps to make your grouping field as the "header" or "trigger" of the accordion action.

1. Go to  Format: Views Accordion Settings and select Grouping field.
2. Check "**Use the group header as the Accordion header**"

[image]

Save View. That's it. Now your Grouping field will act as Views Accordion Header and avoids duplicate headers too.

Hope this helps.